# What's a pantry? Difference from a kitchen

Tags: culture

In our culture, we don't have a pantry in our houses. So I don't quite understand why you make a room called pantry. What's a pantry? Can't you store the things in the kitchen? Aren't the foods more handy if they're in the kitchen when you need them while cooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **pantry**: a small room or closet in which food, dishes, and utensils are kept.

Yes, you *can* store all of those in a kitchen, but that doesn't make it a pantry. A pantry can be a closet within the kitchen, or a separate room or closet. But in any case its *purpose* is the storage of those things. The *purpose* of a kitchen is to cook.

Pantries are rarer than they were, and nowadays are often *secondary* storage rooms. For example you might have a jar of flour in your kitchen, and a big bag of flour in your pantry, and when the jar gets empty you go to to the pantry for more.

Comment: Before the days of refrigerators, it was usual to have a pantry (or 'larder') which had only a small window, or none at all, and thick walls to help keep food cool. When cooking was done using fire, kitchens were hot places. Modern houses are not built with pantries.

Comment: @KateBunting For what value of “modern”? My house (2001) has a pantry, as does my friend’s (2012). Or did you mean to say larder?

Comment: @StephenS - I stand corrected! The Victorian house we lived in when I was a child had been built with a large pantry; the bungalow my parents moved to had only a small built-in cupboard off the kitchen. Neither of the two 20th century houses I have owned has had one at all.

Comment: @KateBunting I can’t recall seeing a house without one, but there’s a blurry line between a small pantry and a large cupboard. To me, if you can stand inside it *at all*, it’s a pantry, but others may draw the line differently.

Comment: Think of it as a walk-in wardrobe for food.