# meaning of 'pantry meal'

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [the transcript of a podcast](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/1089175288).

> LEE: Gim is also a key ingredient in one of Eric's favorite dishes,
> gyeran bap, which literally means egg rice. It's a simple **pantry meal**
> and anyone can whip it up in 10 to 15 minutes.

I wonder what 'pantry meal' is.

Comment: You might also beinterested in https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309237/whats-a-pantry-difference-from-a-kitchen

Comment: @mdewey Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a fixed phrase, to my knowledge, but it's easy to guess. A pantry meal requires only ingredients that you are likely to have in your pantry at home.

The opposite is a recipe that invariably requires you to go to the store and buy some unusual ingredient or other.

Comment: A more common phrase is "store-cupboard meal" with the same meaning.  Further than just lacking unusual ingredients, there may well be no perishable ingredients (like fresh veg or chilled/frozen products).  If there are such ingredients they should be the sort of thing most households would expect to have routinely available, and not too perishable.  Note that *some* definitions of "pantry" include fridge and freezer, but not all. "Pantry" itself isn't commonly used in all varieties of English so the word itself may be rather unfamiliar

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChrisH Given that the recipe is for "egg rice", I'm not sure that definition applies, since eggs are definitely perishable, but they're a thing most people are likely to have on hand.

Comment: @ChrisH ‘Store cupboard’ isn't used that widely in some varieties of English, either (though it's probably easier to infer than ‘pantry’).

Comment: @ChrisH In AmE, "store" is used to refer to what in BrE is referred to as "shop". I assume that in BrE, "store-cupboard" is intended to mean something like "stuff stored in your cupboard", but in AmE, it comes across as an oxymoron.

Comment: @Accumulation interesting. My quick search earlier did give some hits in US units for "store cupboard recipes", despite Google knowing I'm in the UK. I can't escape the American usage of "store" either, though "shop" is of course more common here

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, eggs are perishable, but only on a long timescale (they're routinely kept for months). They don't even need to be refrigerated in most of the world; it's only because they're washed that they must be in the US.